# Centos 7 not loading latest kernel at boot

Tags: centos, kernel

By default, centos 7 comes with kernel version 3.10.x. After installation of centos 7, I have upgraded kernel to 4.6.x that is latest stable version. My system is remote. First, it is very expensive for me to reboot at each kernel update/upgrade. Is there any solution ? Second, if I reboot, still 3.10.x version is loaded. Where is the problem ?

I used following command for upgrading

```
    rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
    yum install http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
    yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml
    reboot
```

Comment: Kindly, provide us the procedure you used to upgrade the kernel

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Is the kernel actually installed? please add the output of `rpm -qa kernel`

Comment: This is the output of above command                                                             kernel-3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: From this output, It seems the Kernel 4.6.x was not installed at all with the procedure you used, but this could be a nice luck reading Otheus answer

Answer (score 7):

You need to edit and rebuild the grub config:

```
sudo grub2-set-default 0
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
sudo reboot
```

This will ensure that grub boots from the latest installed kernel.

Comment: I don't know why this got a downvote. It actually turned out to be the solution when I had this problem.

Comment: this is a helpful answer, in my case, my kernel image was lost for somereason, I need to rebuild the image by : ```dracut -f initramfs-4.4.247-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.img``` first.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a common problem with the latest update to the kernel module.

The CentOS package maintainer seems to have left out or munged the step that builds ***initramfs*** after the new kernel is installed. You're left with an unbootable system.

The steps for fixing this are:

1. Boot into the previous kernel version (in rescue mode).
2. Re-run `dracut` for the newer kernel (this step rebuilds ***initramfs***).

   ```bash
   awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print i++ " : " $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg   # <-- version list
   dracut -f initramfs-{specific version here}.x86_64
   dracut -f initramfs-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.img 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 # <-- example
   ```
3. Re-run `grub2-mkconfig`, or edit grub manually (this step specifies ***initramfs*** image that will be use for new kernel).

   ```bash
   awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print i++ " : " $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
   grub2-set-default {number} # <-- choose your preferred kernel to startup (0, 1, 2, etc.)
   grub2-set-default 0 # <-- example
   grub2-set-default 1 # <-- example
   ```
4. Reboot.

More detailed instructions are found [here](http://advancelinux.blogspot.co.at/2013/06/how-to-rebuild-initrd-or-initramfs-in.html) and [here](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CreateNewInitrd).